# Why does my function arg get type of never?

Tags: typescript

I created a feature of filters for my app. One of the things I need is an update function to change the value of selected filter by id. Here's a very simplified example of what I'm doing:

```js
interface DictionaryItem<Type> {
    value: Type;
    stringify: (value: Type) => string | null;
}

interface Dictionary {
    age: DictionaryItem<number>;
    isNice: DictionaryItem<boolean>;
    nickname: DictionaryItem<string>;
}

const items: Dictionary = {
    age: {
        value: 44,
        stringify: value => String(value),
    },
    isNice: {
        value: true,
        stringify: value => value ? "yes" : null,
    },
    nickname: {
        value: "Joey",
        stringify: value => value,
    },
};

type UpdateFunction = <Type extends keyof Dictionary>(id: Type, value: Dictionary[Type]["value"]) => void;

const update: UpdateFunction = (id, value) => {
    items[id].value = value;

    // Here's the problem - TypeScript thinks that
    // stringify signature is stringify(never)
    const stringified = items[id].stringify(value);

    console.log(stringified);
};

update("age", 45);
```

The problem is that I can't call `items[id].stringify(value);`, because TypeScript parses the `stringify` method as `stringify(value: never)` in this case.

How can I make TypeScript understand what's the expected type of `stringify()` in my `update()` function? And where did that `never` come from?

Comment: TypeScript can't "see" arbitrary generic relationships, it just sees `items[id].stringify()` as a union of functions and then doesn't accept a union of arguments, as per  [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  You could perform the refactoring as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaZ8om) shows.  Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz sorry for delayed reply. It works indeed, I thought myself of using an extra type to just map keys to their return value types, but I didn't know how to map it to a type using `DictionaryItem<Type>`. So I guess it's not possible to avoid this extra type? If not, would you mind adding an answer and grab some points? :)

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't take

```
interface Dictionary {
  age: DictionaryItem<number>;
  isNice: DictionaryItem<boolean>;
  nickname: DictionaryItem<string>;
}
```

and "notice" that every property is `DictionaryItem<T>` for some `T`.  When you write `items[id].stringify`, TypeScript does not see any generic relationship there; instead it just widens the generic to its constraint and gives you a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions:

```
  const f = items[id].stringify
  // const f: ((value: number) => string | null) | 
  //          ((value: boolean) => string | null) | 
  //          ((value: string) => string | null)
```

And when you try to call a union of functions, the compiler will insist upon the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of their arguments, to be safe.  See [the TypeScript 3.3 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) for more information.  This turns out to be [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) (since `number & boolean & string` can't exist) so it won't let you call the function at all.

The compiler has lost track of the *correlation* between `items[id].stringify` and `value`.  It worries that maybe `items[id].stringify` might accept, say, a `number`, but that `value` might be, say, a `boolean`.  Even though you can see that such a thing is impossible (or unlikely enough not to worry about), the compiler cannot.  As far as it can see, you have a union of functions and a union of arguments, and they are not correlated.

This is therefore the issue described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

---

The recommended approach in such situations is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), and involves refactoring to use a "basic" mapping interface, and generic indexes into that interface, and generic indexes into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that interface.

It turns out that your code is actually quite close to the required refactoring.  The only real change we have to make is to rewrite `Dictionary` as a mapped type over that "basic" interface:

```
interface DictionaryMap {
  age: number;
  isNice: boolean;
  nickname: string;
}

type Dictionary =
  { [K in keyof DictionaryMap]: DictionaryItem<DictionaryMap[K]> }
```

And now instead of referring to `Dictionary[Type]["value"]`, we can say `DictionaryMap[Type]`:

```
type UpdateFunction = <K extends keyof Dictionary>(
  id: K, value: DictionaryMap[K]) => void;
```

Now everything just works.  We can see that `items[id].stringify` is now of a single generic function type instead of a union:

```
  const f = items[id].stringify
  // const f: (value: DictionaryMap[K]) => string | null
```

And since `value` is of type `DictionaryMap[K]`, then `f(value)` is acceptable.

---

You might think that there is no difference between your definition of `Dictionary` and the changed version, and indeed they are completely equivalent (if you hover over `Dictionary` with IntelliSense you'll see the same type as yours).  But the refactoring explicitly lets the compiler know that `Dictionary` has a generic relationship with `DictionaryItem`, instead of just leaving that relationship implied.  Maybe in some future version of TypeScript, such implicit relationships will be observable to the compiler.  But for now, you need to spell it out by introducing a more basic type and mapping over it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgEIgAmehRSAlsAC4QBOAZuUgCKPwWjAPah2ATwCSbMAB4AKuJgQAfHQYMAbpgCuEAFxJFygNz0NUFu2YBzRp3GGAFNox7DxiAEokAXjWW1sA2SAA+xDoYGGYaAL745kysHNyIfAJCoiAS6hpIIDYG6YIiYlIyssA6YABGHCoxeYxQAHICRfwlWRLSEHI1wsIYECDADYlEwAIA1iQdGaXZ5X2ygbbjcQka8KKWTDJQhp2ZZX65GgVFBHlaukUALPcANBMMa8H2jkiuen5qAMpWWwuO5eF43WLgpqtdqGa43b53QxWPRQm7vOwOQw-ZD+RFuZAAfiQACJxNASUhDFUomiGJDXlN4LNwFdXkQcYYSShhBBxCS6RYgR8sfjfnicYKkAy4mZEiwlMgAKowaggNgAMR0wC6wDOCkVSAgAA82MBqFAkNM+cJOMUTksVE5GNQPIqnmL5rqlgBtTwAXR9JJxJP9Pglwhdcu2uxYSB0qvVRRVas12t1Z2d1A9OPDanhGkYBx9Lv9ADocWccdG8jtgHs7b59n0oCXqOWMZ9XgB6btIOsN5wggnU6p1dh5pAYsIRKI+cJOYfuJADIYjYCT6fhGkYedIRecqfCmyb48zndeLa12NHoKYxgQWhNosttsd4+fJfeGsx+trssYMINhOJ2nAPtQXiNEQsQ-vGiZsE4JKXAKSD3AArJB9DxPQcxkGkADigy0AWSRsFwPDHIsPQVPI+avIe8hQW8H6il+Hinne56RNEiTYYWyTkWklHdOIACyIAwOcDCXKOtQcExRDNG0iCGKuwyjApxAzHMhgYkxfEMAqyj2lR4h+K8uBID6ADSSRWjadrCWU4kwP6RwLCJvRyE5SwuTZ-pqAZRADnGL5gIcJkiWcJFEDJUkaIejxSkQoFfJWeKAneX5gq8MrQspbIIp6yLsKi7K3rYnzYncfyekgxJkhSVKzhgUp5RoTIspAcLlYe3K8vyyUVSKaU1RKdxtXSMFXkQRnKvBEBajqJz6rZJpmha9niLakVlE6rwuoY1k5kiu2+RJ-mTpokbULBIVwamyYLUtGZNlmJ0EpOMXNuFb4VmNnqwcFN6Nj9ralmWqU9n292cM4h4+RIfnWWGtVbi1M0MPdoHgWcYXg+2kMseI2VA-2uz-oBwE44+mGypjCaPYhyEeuhdPSgksRAA)

Comment: Thank you, jcalz. One last question - are you sure it wouldn't be possible to somehow use `infer` keyword to infer the generic type from the type in this case?

Comment: I can’t be sure it wouldn’t “somehow” be possible but the `infer` keyword wouldn’t help in any situation I can imagine.  The linked GitHub issues above (30581 and 47109) are as much information as I know about this